# VBA Sum up values in row based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a VBA code based on conditions: 
-if orders have the same value in column D, column F, column P and column P = unit then sum up values in column Q; if column P=amount then sum up values in column S.

```
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim Cumulative As Variant
Dim y As Long

With Wb2.Worksheets.Item(1)
    lastrow1 = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Cumulative = 0
    startrow = 4 'Row where your data starts + 1, so row 3 + 1 in this case

    For y = startrow To lastrow1
        If Range("P" & y - 1).Value = "Unit" Then
            Cumulative = Cumulative + Range("Q" & y - 1).Value
            If Range("F" & y).Value = Range("F" & y - 1).Value And Range("D" & y).Value = Range("D" & y - 1).Value And Range("P" & y).Value = Range("P" & y - 1).Value Then
                Range("Q" & y - 1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Cumulative
                Cumulative = 0
            End If
        ElseIf Range("P" & y - 1).Value = "Amount" Then
                Cumulative = Cumulative + Range("S" & y - 1).Value
            If Range("F" & y).Value = Range("F" & y - 1).Value And Range("D" & y).Value = Range("D" & y - 1).Value And Range("P" & y).Value = Range("P" & y - 1).Value Then
                Range("S" & y - 1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Cumulative
                Cumulative = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next y

End With
```

But the code doesn't work, I got the range object error 1004 in line `Range("S" & y - 1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Cumulative`.

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? what range are you looking for ?

Comment: Examine the `Range` argument when it fails

Comment: Note that all of this could be done with formulas, without the need of VBA.

Comment: `"S" & y - 1 & .Rows.Count` is certainly not correct: why do append `Rows.Count` there? It will concatenate the digits of two numbers (`y-1` and `.Rows.Count`), resulting in a row number that is beyond the acceptable range. It is meaningless.

Comment: What is `Wb2.Worksheets.Item(1)`?  I can't see if you've defined `Wb2` anywhere.  Also it could be written as `Wb2.Worksheets(1)` - but would be much better to write `Wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")` just in case you move the order of sheets around.  You use `With` but only reference it twice with `.Rows.Count` - surely each `Range` and `Cell` should be `.Range` and `.Cell` otherwise those will reference the active sheet.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use VBA and not formulas?

Comment: I want to use VBA because i need to apply it to lot of files. ".Rows.Count).End(xlUp)" to make the sum up value appear in the last used row of this column

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong `Range("S" & y - 1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Cumulative`

It evaluates to something like for example `S9:1048576` , which will throw error 1004.

Change it to :

`Range("S" & y - 1 & ":S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Cumulative`